# O que é o operador “-->” em C?

Tags: c

Eu nunca vi esse operador antes, apenas outro parecido `->`, mas não faz sentido no contexto desse código.

**Código**

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    int x = 10;
    while (x --> 0) { // x goes to 0
        printf("%d ", x);
    }
}
```

**Saída**

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na verdade, o que está acontecendo é `x--` maior que `0`, ou seja, o `while` está decrementando `x` enquanto `x` maior que `0`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 10;

    while (x-- > 0) { // x goes to 0
        printf("%d ", x);
    }

    printf("\nX = %d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

> Veja online:https://repl.it/@Dadinel/StainedFunnyProcedures#main.c

Perceba que no final do `while`, `x` será `-1`.

Comment: Vi o "// x goes to 0" e resolvi compartilhar um algo a mais. Todos professores de Ciência Eng. de Computação que tive me sugeriram a regra de ouro: SEMPRE evite usar comandos go-to em LP's de alto nível (para não dizer nunca use). Não sei se o trecho deste post foi encontrado na web. É bom lembrar dessa regra porque, muito embora certas LPs de alto nível contenham o go-to, esse comando pode gerar issues, e no mínimo atrapalhar a legibilidade do fonte. Como programador iniciante, confie em mim, chegarão momentos em que aparentemente um go-to resolveria tudo, mas resista e faça de outra forma.